# Dropping rows in pandas with .index

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I came across the below line of code, which gives an error when '.index' is not present in it.

```
print(df.drop(df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index).rename(columns={'Weight': 'Weight (oz.)'}))
```

What is the purpose of '.index' while using drop in pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), you can use `drop` with `index`:

```
   A  B   C   D
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11

df.drop([0, 1]) # Here 0 and 1 are the index of the rows
```

Output:

```
   A  B   C   D
2  8  9  10  11
```

In this case it will drop the first 2 rows.
With `.index` in your example, you find the rows where `Quantity=0`and retrieve their index(and then use like in the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

this is the detail about `.drop()` method:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

`.drop()` method need a parameter 'label' which is a list of index labels(when `axis=0`, which is the default case) or columns labels (when `axis=1`).
`df[df['Quantity'] == 0]` returns a DataFrame where `Quantity=0`, but what we need is the index label where `Quantity=0`, so .index is needed.